# g.setColor(Color.BLACK) fails to compile - undefined method

Tags: java

I have this program:

```
package com.systino.drzzle;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import com.sun.prism.Graphics;
import com.sun.prism.paint.Color;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static int width = 300;
    public static int height = width/16*9;
    public static int scale = 3;

    private Thread thread;
    private JFrame frame;
    private boolean running = false;

    public Game () {
        Dimension size = new Dimension(width*scale, height*scale);
        setPreferredSize(size);

        frame = new JFrame();
    }

    public synchronized void start () {
        running = true;
        thread = new Thread(this, "Display");
        thread.start();
    }

    public synchronized void stop () {

        running = false;
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public void run () {
        while (running) {
            update();
            render();
        }
    }

    public void update () {

    }

    public void render () {
        BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy ();
        if (bs == null) {
            createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }

        Graphics g = (Graphics) bs.getDrawGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK); //Error is shown here..
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        ((java.awt.Graphics) g).dispose();
        bs.show();
    }

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        Game game = new Game();
        game.frame.setResizable(false);
        game.frame.setTitle("Drizzle");
        game.frame.add(game);
        game.frame.pack();
        game.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        game.frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        game.frame.setVisible(true);

        game.start();
    }
}
```

The compiler complains that `Graphics.setColor` is an undefined method.

I have imported `BufferStrategy` and also `Graphics` and `Color`.

Is there something else I need to import?

I am using Eclipse release 2 (4.4.2)

Comment: Quite clear the error message, there is no `setColor` in `com.sun.prism.Graphics`, did you mean to import `java.awt.Graphics`?

Comment: i have imported java.awt.Graphics

Comment: your code even shows that you did import `com.sun.prism.Graphics`, so where did you import `java.awt.Graphics`

Comment: i removed com.sun.prism.Graphics and imported java.awt.Graphics but i am still getting the same error

Comment: shall i remove the import com.sun.prism.paint.Color; too?

Comment: even if i change g.setColor to setClip, i am getting an error.

Comment: I admit this is a bit off-topic to your actual question, but I highly suggest you consider using an IDE.  IntelliJ, Eclipse, NetBeans, anything.  Any of those will prevent errors like these.

Comment: i am using Eclipse IDE (4.4.2)

Comment: i removed com.sun.prism.paint.Color; and its working fine now... thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I removed import com.sun.prism.paint.Color and it worked, not sure why I hope it helps.